# Subtracting minimum value from all values in a column

Tags: sql

Is there a another way to subtract the smallest value from all the values of a column, effectively offset the values?

The only way I have found becomes horribly complicated for more complex queries.

```
CREATE TABLE offsettest(value NUMBER);
INSERT INTO offsettest VALUES(100);
INSERT INTO offsettest VALUES(200);
INSERT INTO offsettest VALUES(300);
INSERT INTO offsettest VALUES(400);

SELECT value - (SELECT MIN(value) FROM offsettest) FROM offsettest;

DROP TABLE offsettest;
```

I'd like to limit it to a single query (no stored procedures, variables, etc) if possible and standard SQL is preferred (although I am using Oracle).

Comment: What is horribly complicated with your solution? You've got to find MIN value hence your aggregated select. Then you've got to subtract hence your final select.

Comment: I don't think there's an easier syntax than that...
You can get creative and join that table to itself, I guess, but it'll definitely get more convoluted...

Answer (score 10):

I believe this works as of ANSI 1999.

`SELECT value - MIN(value) OVER() FROM offsettest;`

Answer (score -1):

It would have helped you see your actual query, though, since depending on whether you need to manipulate more than one column this way, and the various minimums come from different rows, there may be more efficient ways to do it. If the OVER() works for you, then fine.